# Automatic renaming of the google form uploaded response and files as a certain form input

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-api, google-forms

I am new in Google Script and I want to know whether there is a script to do the following

1. I have a form with certain inputs for example `CourseCode`, `CourseNo`, `Class` and I want to have output response as `CourseCodeCourseNo-Class`
2. I want the forms to be saved in directories depending on the department, for example, physics files go to `physics` folder

[image: the form is attached as image]

Answer (score 0):

- When you create a Google form, you can specify a [destination](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/2917686) spreadsheet for the responses
- You can access the response store in this spreadsheet with Apps Script and e.g. create an additional column where the responses to your questions are merged to `CourseCodeCourseNo-Class`.
- You can evaluate the response to the question `Department` and synchronize the response row to a secondary spreadsheet - depending on the response value
- You can implement an [installable On Form Submit trigger for spreadsheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) to automatically synchronize the secondary sheets on each form submit.

Below is an example code meeting your needs. Please refer to Apps Script documentation for [Google Forms](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet) and [Google Spreadsheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms) to obtain a better understanding and modify the sample as desired.

**Sample:**

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet=ss.getActiveSheet();
  var lastRow=ss.getLastRow();
  //the first column contains the timestamp
  var department=sheet.getRange(lastRow,2).getValue();
  var subjectCode=sheet.getRange(lastRow,3).getValue();
  var courseCode=sheet.getRange(lastRow,4).getValue();
  var courseNo=sheet.getRange(lastRow,5).getValue();
  var newResponse=courseCode.toString()+courseNo.toString()+"-"+subjectCode.toString();
  sheet.getRange(lastRow,7).setValue(newResponse);
  var secodarySheetId;
  switch(department) {
  case "Physics":
    secodarySheetId="XXX";//Paste here the Id of the destinationsheet in the Physics folder
    break;
  case "Chemistry":
    secodarySheetId="XXX";//Paste here the Id of the destinationsheet in the Chemistry folder
    break;
  case "Math":
    secodarySheetId="XXX";//Paste here the Id of the destinationsheet in the Maths folder
    break;
  }
 var rowContents=sheet.getRange(lastRow,1,1,sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
 SpreadsheetApp.openById(secodarySheetId).getSheetByName("Sheet1").appendRow(rowContents[0]);
}
```

> Open the destination spreadsheet, `Tools->Script Editor`, paste the
>   following code, save it and add a `Form Submit` trigger through
>   `Edit->Current Projects triggers`

[image]

Please note that this is one of several possible solutions, it is also possible to e.g. process the responses from a script attached to the Form, rather than the destination spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your response and helpful script, but I still have unsolvable problem when I perform the script: 
**"Document 1aPXI357UfQGdJnoxYfvtSq7GXhfizSSC is missing (perhaps it was deleted, or you don't have read access?) (line 30, file "Code")DetailsDismiss"**

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet=ss.getActiveSheet();
  var lastRow=ss.getLastRow();
  Logger.log("1k2rOZfXjXHciPQh1pXn7-GP-p3rccMgT")
  Logger.log("1iWL9jbVNWIqn_mkSxkIWu73uwxsrw2f7")
  Logger.log("1aPXI357UfQGdJnoxYfvtSq7GXhfizSSC")

  //the first column contains the timestamp

  var department=sheet.getRange(lastRow,2).getValue();
  var subjectCode=sheet.getRange(lastRow,3).getValue();
  var courseCode=sheet.getRange(lastRow,4).getValue();
  var courseNo=sheet.getRange(lastRow,5).getValue();
  var newResponse=courseCode.toString()+courseNo.toString()+"-"+subjectCode.toString();
  sheet.getRange(lastRow,7).setValue(newResponse);
  var secodarySheetId;
  switch(department) {
  case "Physics":
    secodarySheetId="1k2rOZfXjXHciPQh1pXn7-GP-p3rccMgT";//Paste here the Id of the destinationsheet in the Physics folder
    break;
  case "Chemistry":
    secodarySheetId="1iWL9jbVNWIqn_mkSxkIWu73uwxsrw2f7";//Paste here the Id of the destinationsheet in the Chemistry folder
    break;
  case "Math":
    secodarySheetId="1aPXI357UfQGdJnoxYfvtSq7GXhfizSSC";//Paste here the Id of the destinationsheet in the Maths folder
    break;
  }
 var rowContents=sheet.getRange(lastRow,1,1,sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
 SpreadsheetApp.openById(secodarySheetId).getSheetByName("CR (Responses)").appendRow(rowContents[0]);
}
```

Comment: Hello @Murad AlDamen, I just saw your reply - `Document 1aPXI357UfQGdJnoxYfvtSq7GXhfizSSC is missing` most likely means that you copied the sheet Id wrong or that the document is contained in a folder to which you do not have access (sharing settings?) PS: I will be notified about your comment if you inset a `@` before my name.